# Ruby Rails Remove Comments from CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I'm new to rails and am trying to process a CSV file, some files will have comments at the start of the CSV file, comments are marked with #. If there a way I can delete these rows? I don't have to just ignore them as I want to save the file without comments.

sample file:

```
#-----------------------
# report --------------
#-----------------------
Date, transctions
20100923, 34
20200110, 56
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CSV library has a [`skip_lines`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new) options:

> When setting an object responding to `match`, every line matching it is considered a comment and ignored during parsing. When set to a String, it is first converted to a Regexp. When set to `nil` no line is considered a comment. If the passed object does not respond to `match`, `ArgumentError` is thrown.

This should work for you:

```
CSV.foreach(file, skip_lines: /^#/, headers: true) do |row|
  # ...
end
```

`/^#/` matches lines starting with `#`.

Comment: Thanks but I want to write the save the new file without the comments only.

Comment: @icantcode when you said _"trying to process a CSV file"_ I assumed you wanted to do something with the data. So your actual question is simply how to remove lines starting with `#`?

Answer (score 1):

Adding something to **@Stefan** answer (all credit goes to him for the skip_lines tip), assuming your csv file is **input.csv** :

```rb
require "csv"
CSV.open("output.csv", "wb") do |output_csv|
  CSV.foreach("input.csv", skip_lines: /^#/, headers: true) do |row|
    # ...
    output_csv << row
  end
end
```

This way you will end with a file **output.csv** without those comments.

**EDIT:**
If you want also the header, you can do:

```rb
CSV.open("output.csv", "wb") do |output_csv|
  CSV.foreach("input.csv", skip_lines: /^#/, headers: true).with_index(0) do |row, i|
    output_csv << row.headers if i == 0
    puts row
    output_csv << row
  end
end
```

...It's not as clean as I want but fits your needs ;)

Comment: Thank you. Almost there.. The file now doesn't have headers.

Comment: Actually I can just leave out headers:true and it works the way I want it to. I am sending the resulting files through smarterCSV so all is good, thank you.